# XAML/Silverlight CheckBox ToolTip

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

Im trying to add a tooltip to a checkbox in XAML, however all i get is errors:

```
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
          <ToolTip x:Name="ToolTipDelete" Content="Delete" />
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```

Anyone know how I might add this to a checkbox?

Silverlight 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Simple text:**

```
<CheckBox ToolTip="Delete"/>
```

**More control over display:**

```
<CheckBox>
    <CheckBox.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock>Delete</TextBlock>
    </CheckBox.ToolTip>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: Hmmm, cannot find any Tooltip property on Silverlight Checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight 4

It worked for me

```
<CheckBox>
     <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
          <TextBlock>Voluntary</TextBlock>
     </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</CheckBox>
```